# Bootstrap type-ahead and angular-schema-form not working

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-schema-form

The filter "liveSearchEmployee()"  does not trigger on the parent scope of the controller. It appears to be being ignored.

```
<input style="width:250px" type="text" ng-model="$$value$$"     ng-change="changeEmployee($$value$$)"    typeahead="(items.lastname + ', ' + items.firstname) for items in liveSearchEmployee($$value$$) "   typeahead-on-select="selectedPatientConsult($item)"    typeahead-min-length="3"   ng-hide="{{form.schema.readOnlyMode}}"    name="{{form.key}}" id="{{form.key}}" title="{{form.title}}"   ng-required="form.required" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "parent scope of the controller" I guess you mean its on the scope outside of the form?

The directive `sf-schema` has an isolated scope so nothing outside is inherited.

Try putting what you need onto the form definition object instead for your field type.

```
<input style="width:250px" type="text" ng-model="$$value$$"     
       ng-change="form.changeEmployee($$value$$)"  
       typeahead="(items.lastname + ', ' + items.firstname) for items in form.liveSearchEmployee($$value$$) "   
       typeahead-on-select="form.selectedPatientConsult($item)"    
       typeahead-min-length="3"   
       ng-hide="{{form.schema.readOnlyMode}}"    
       name="{{form.key}}" id="{{form.key}}" 
       title="{{form.title}}" ng-required="form.required" />
```

Or even better, wrap it in a directive that exports these functions.

Comment: yes its the scope outside schema-form, i.e. the scope of the controller.